# Question about pools, object is not spawning

Tags: aframe

I have a question about pools (object pooling). I made a script just to test if i can see the object i want to spawn after i press the trigger, but it doesn't work:

(app)
https://pooltest.glitch.com

(code)
https://glitch.com/edit/#!/join/2568a87c-d8e8-475c-b5a8-cf03f60f7285

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a syntax error in your code:

```
let pool = sceneEl.components.[pool__pew];
```

should be:

```
let pool = sceneEl.components["pool__pew"];
```